# Is there a way to combine multiple strings using Regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Having an issue with Regex and not really understanding its usefulness right now.
Trying to extrapolate data from a file.  file consists of first name, last name, grade

File:

```
Peter Jenkins: A  
Robert Right: B  
Kim Long: C  
Jim Jim: B
```

Opening file code:

```
##Regex Code  r'([A-Za-z]+)(: B)
regcode = r'([A-Za-z]+)(: B)'

answer=re.findall(regcode,file)
return answer
```

The expected result is first name last name.  The given result is last name and letter grade.  How do I just get the first name and last name for all B grades?

Comment: Do you need regex? I think simple split and some filter / complrehension should fo the job

Comment: unfortunately regex is needed or this would not be an issue

Comment: Ok, *why* do you need regex? There are easier (IMO) solutions.. But the regex way: `r'([A-Za-z]+)(: B)'` matches a word (in 1st group) followed by `: B` (matched to the second group). Just match one more word and it should work

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Its for a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you must use regex for this task, here's a simple regex solution that returns the full name:

`'(.*): B'`

Which works in this case because:

`(.*)` returns all text  up to a match of `: B`

[Click here](https://regex101.com/r/mtYouk/2) to see my test and matching output. I recommend this site for your regex testing needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex:

```
students = '''Peter Jenkins: A
Robert Right: B
Kim Long: C
Jim Jim: B'''
    
for x in students.split('\n'):
    string = x.split(': ')
    if string[1] == 'B':
        print(string[0])

# Robert Right
# Jim Jim
```

or

```
[x[0:-3] for x in students.split('\n') if x[-1] == 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

If a regex solution is required (I perosnally like the solution of Roman Zhak more), put inside a group what you are interested in, i.e. the first name and the second name. Follows colon and B:

```py
import re

file = """
Peter Jenkins: A  
Robert Right: B  
Kim Long: C  
Jim Jim: B
"""

regcode = r'([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z]+): B'
answer=re.findall(regcode,file,re.)
print(answer) # [('Robert', 'Right'), ('Jim', 'Jim')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a capturing group (`'()'`) to your expression. Everything outside the group will be ignored, even if it matches the expression.

```
re.findall('(\w+\s+\w+):\s+B', file)
#['Robert Right', 'Jim Jim']
```

`'\w'` is any alphanumeric character, `'\s'` is any space-like character.

You can add two groups, one for the first name and one for the last name:

```
re.findall('(\w+)\s+(\w+):\s+B', data)
#[('Robert', 'Right'), ('Jim', 'Jim')]
```

The latter will not work if there are more than two names on one line.